My texture view display a non-centered zoomed camera preview
I am new to Android/Java development and need some guidance from an expert.
I am trying to display a camera preview on TextureView, but the displayed preview is zoomed and not centered.
Here are some code snippets:
For the camera initialization:
protected void initializeCamera() {
        if (this.context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: Camera permission not granted");
        }
        try {
            camManager = (CameraManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            textureView = new AutoFitTextureView(this.context);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            textureView.setLayoutParams(params);
            textureView.setAspectRatio(cameraResolution.previewSize.getHeight(), cameraResolution.previewSize.getWidth());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: Camera feature check failed:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

Open camera:
 private void OpenCamera(String templateType) throws CameraAccessException {
        ///... chechinkg the permissions

        ...

        SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(cameraResolution.previewSize.getWidth(), cameraResolution.previewSize.getHeight());
        ...

        imageReaderHqCapture = ImageReader.newInstance(cameraResolution.captureSize.getWidth(), cameraResolution.captureSize.getHeight(), currentHqImageFormat, numProcessedImages);
        lSurfaces.add(imageReaderHqCapture.getSurface());
        camManager.openCamera(camId, new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
                camDevice = cameraDevice;
                Log.d(TAG, "onOpened");
                try {
                    cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(lSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                           ...
                            try {
                                configureCaptureHqBuilder(templateType, characteristics);
                                configureCapturePreviewBuilder(characteristics);
                                scheduleNextCapture(0);// start scheduler
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                               ...
                            }
                        }

                      
                    }, null);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ...
                }
            }



           
    }

If you need any further details please ask. I can't show all code here
